# Calculation for each row of df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of >150,000 rows, something like

```
|   ID  |   CATEGORY    |   START_DATE      |   END_DATE        |   NEW_COL_I_WANT_TO_ADD   |
|   0   |   A           |   01/07/2020      |   02/07/2020      |   1                       |
|   1   |   A           |   28/06/2020      |   null            |   0                       |
|   2   |   B           |   28/06/2020      |   29/06/2020      |   0                       |
```

I want to add a column where for each row `i` I have the count of all the (different) records with certain conditions:

```
(1) CATEGORY[i] == CATEGORY[j] 
(2) & START_DATE[j] <= START_DATE[i]
(3) & END_DATE[j] null | END_DATE[j] > END_DATE[I]
```

So the new column `COUNT` will contain the count of all the records `j` that have the same category (1), started before (2) and ended afterwards (3) (basically the number of pending records `j` at the moment of creation of `i`), which for the record with `ID 0` is `1`.

How can I efficiently perform this operation for each row?

I tried assigning `df.apply(lambda record: df[filtered_according_to_conditions].count(), axis=1)` to the new column but it doesn’t seem to work.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want. Could you put some sample data what you have and what sort of output you want?

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between indices i and j? i.e : i = j - 5 ?

Comment: I edited the question to be more specific about the meaning of the operation

Comment: @Chernabog Here `j` th row refer to `i + 1`, Right? or can it be any row with same category?

Comment: `j` is any row for which all the conditions apply (same category, started before, ended afterwards, not `i`)

Comment: So you basically want to group on category and check the conditions.

Comment: exactly @ShubhamSharma.

Answer (score 0):

`df.apply` seems like it should work. For each record, you can perform boolean operations against the rest of the table to generate a vector of bool, then sum (count) up the number of `True` values to determine the number of matching other rows.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Sample Data
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
ID|CATEGORY|START_DATE|END_DATE
0|A|2020-07-01|2020-07-02
1|A|2020-06-28|null
2|B|2020-06-28|2020-06-29
"""), sep='|', parse_dates=['START_DATE', 'END_DATE'])

df['NEW_COL_I_WANT_TO_ADD'] = df.apply(
    lambda record: (
        (df['ID'] != record['ID']) & # Not the current record
        (record['CATEGORY'] == df.CATEGORY) &  # condition 1
        (df.START_DATE <= record.START_DATE) & # condition 2
        (df.END_DATE.isnull() | (df.END_DATE > record.END_DATE)) # etc.
    ).sum(), # sum() will count number of items that match all conditions
    axis=1
)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
ID CATEGORY START_DATE   END_DATE  NEW_COL_I_WANT_TO_ADD
 0        A 2020-07-01 2020-07-02                      1
 1        A 2020-06-28        NaT                      0
 2        B 2020-06-28 2020-06-29                      0
```

Comment: I tried this on 150,000 rows and it takes 25 minutes. Seems a more efficient method is needed.

Comment: Indeed, apply takes even longer for me